# Запуск mystem на windows

Tags: cmd, exe

Я пытаюсь воспользоваться консольной програмой от яндекса. Называется mystem.
Инфо тут https://tech.yandex.ru/mystem/.

Вкратце, она получает на вход русский текст и приводит существительные к именительному падежу и глаголы к инфинитиву.

Но я никак не могу приобразовать текст.
Я делаю так:
1. Закинул .exe в корневую папку.
2. Запускаю cmd, в ней пишу "mystem.exe я люблю"
Ожидаю что "люблю" превратится в "любить"
Получаю такую ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или такую если пытаюсь загрузить текст из файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема во втором случае кажется с кодировкой.
Очень прошу помощи.

Comment: *Проблема во втором случае кажется с кодировкой.* Программа желает UTF-8. А получает CP1251. Потому и обижается. Или конвертируйте файл, или укажите в опциях кодировку. PS. К сожалению, документация ничего не говорит про BOM - возможно, она к его наличию или отсутствию индифферентна, но надо проверять.

Answer (score 1):

> -e
>   Кодировка ввода/вывода. Возможные варианты: cp866, cp1251, koi8-r, utf-8 (по умолчанию).

```
mystem -e cp1251 input
```

По первому случаю, не уверен за пайпы в win, но мне кажется, что вы неправильно передаёте ввод(он ведь пытается файл найти).
Попробуйте так:

```
echo "Я люблю" | mystem -e cp1251
```

Comment: Спасибо, кажется он начал отрабатывать, но все еще не понимает кодировку.

Comment: А какая у вас кодировка?

Comment: файл я попытался сохранить во всех вариантах что предлагает блокнот - ANSI, UTF-8 и юникод.

Comment: Юникод - не кодировка, а стандарт кодирования. Кто додумался так назвать формат? Это utf-16?

Comment: Не знаю, но есть сдвиг =)
В таком формате ввода echo "Я люблю" | mystem -e cp1251 с кодировкой cp866 начал работать)
Сейчас попробую через R запустить и вообще красота будет)